# many digits in querySelector

Tags: javascript

how you add numbers to the querySelector (so I don't have to write them all manually) this is a script for one unnamed game)

```
setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelector("#village_3 > td:nth-child(11) > a").click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);
```

this example

```
setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelector("#village(allnumbers) > td:nth-child(11) > a").click();    }, (Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);
```

village_4
village_5
village_6
village_7
(allnumbers IS ID village)

how do i do that

```
document.querySelector ("# village_3> td: nth-child (11)> a")
```

they were not needed for the village numbers in this case number 3

so I don't have to do many code to replace these with one

```
document.querySelector ("# village_1> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_2> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_3> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_4> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_5> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_6> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_7> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_8> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_9> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_10> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_11> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_12> td: nth-child (11)> a")
document.querySelector ("# village_13> td: nth-child (11)> a")
```

this order opens this link

```
<a href="/game.php?village=97&amp;screen=place&amp;target=41&amp;" onclick="Accountmanager.farm.openRallyPoint(41, event)"><img src="https://dscs.innogamescdn.com/asset/028772ed/graphic/buildings/place.png" title="" alt="" class=""></a>
```

can it be done differently? just maybe

screen = place & target =

to click on it when the script sees this text?

Comment: Use a `for` loop with template literals in the selector to interpolate the currently iterated number.

Comment: Don't use ids with numbers at all. Make `village_X` a class `village`. Depending on the actual use-case you could also use an _"id begins with"_ (`^=`) selector.

Comment: can you give me an example of a code here new in programming @Terry

Comment: @Andreas give me example code thanx

Comment: Define a different standard class for all these elements and use that in QuerySelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^=` and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a NodeList of all the anchors you want, and then `click()` them using a `forEach` loop.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('[id^="village"] td:nth-child(11) a').forEach(a => a.click());
}, (Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);
```

A better approach would be to give them a common `class` so you don't have to use the IDs.